# Linting swift project that depends on objective C project with Cocoapods fails

Tags: swift, cocoapods, facebook-sdk-4.0, podspec

I created a project in swift that depends on Facebook SDK (Which is wrote in objective C and downloaded as sources by default).

While I was working on the project with my mac, everything worked great

 I create the following pod file :

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
   use_frameworks!
   target 'MyProj' do
       pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.9'

end
```

run ** pod install** and I was good to go (Facebook downloaded as a framework so I didn't have any mix of obj-c and swift in my code).

Now I finished my project and want to upload it to Cocoapods so I created the following podspec:

`Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name         = "MyProj"
    s.version      = '0.0.1'
    s.platform     = :ios, '8.0'
    s.requires_arc = true
    s.summary      = "summery"
    s.homepage     = "https://www.google.com"
    s.license      = 'Apache License, Version 2.0'
    s.author       = { "Asaf" => "asaf@a.b" }
    s.source       = { :git => 'https://github.com/asaf.git', :tag => '0.0.1'}
    s.dependency 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.9'
    s.source_files = 'Source/myfile.swift'`

end

To verify that my pod spec is correct I lint it using

```
pod spec lint mypodspec.podspec --use-libraries --verbose
```

but I'm getting

> - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it. The Swift Pod being used is: myProj) during validation.

Anyone knows what should I do to solve this issue?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to myself.
 
Updating Cocoapods to version 1.0.0 (currently in beta ) and remove the "--use-libraries" from the lint command, solved the issue.